# String Interpolation in Ragel

Tags: c, ragel

I am trying to implement a language, and I'm using Ragel as a lexer (and bison as a parser).  I would like to be able to support string interpolation within my language, but I'm not sure how to come about doing this.

My lexer uses a scanner like the following for the main part of the language:

```
sstring = "'" ( ( any -- "'" ) | ( '\\' any ) )* "'";
# dstring = ?;
main := |*
   comment => {};
   '(' => { ADD_TOKEN(LPAREN); };
   ')' => { ADD_TOKEN(RPAREN); };
   # ...
   sstring => { ADD_TOKEN2(STRING); };
   # dstring => ?; 
*|;
```

What would I have to do to be able to handle string interpolation like `"hello #{world}"`?

Answer (score 1):

The inner content of the braces can be a full expression. The interpolated string will translate to a concatenation operation. This is too much for the lexer. You need the power of the parser.  Therefore recognize three different kinds of tokens within each interpolated string:

```
istring_start = "'" ( ( any -- "'" ) | ( '\\' any ) )* "#{";
istring_middle = "}" ( ( any -- "'" ) | ( '\\' any ) )* "#{";
istring_end = "}" ( ( any -- "'" ) | ( '\\' any ) )* "'";
```

In the parser you'd have rules like:

```
istring : istring_prefix expr ISTRING_END 
                ;
istring_prefix : ISTRING_START
               | istring_prefix expr ISTRING_MIDDLE 
               ;
```

These rules build the syntax tree or compile bytecode or whatever you intend as code for the string concatenation operation.

Comment: I might have to do this, but it's still not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with an action associated with finishing the string token. In that action you could then iterate over through ts to te and add the logic for your string interpolation and emit the tokens in the action instead.

Something like this, which probably only cover the most basic forms might help you get started:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum token { STR, STR_I };

void emit(enum token tok, const char* start, const char* end) {
  if (start == end)
    return;
  switch(tok) {
    case STR:
      printf("STR(\"%.*s\") ", (int)(end - start), start); break;
    case STR_I:
      printf("STR_I(%.*s) ", (int)(end - start), start); break;
  }
}


%%{
machine interpolation;
write data;

action interpolate {
  // this is the data input without ""
  const char* data_start = ts + 1;
  const char* data_end = te - 1;

  // Use this to walk through the token to find interpolation points
  const char *tok_start = data_start;
  const char *tok_end = data_start;

  for (;tok_end <= data_end; tok_end++) {

    // Does it contain #{ ?
    if (strncmp(tok_end,"#{", 2) == 0) {
      emit(STR, tok_start, tok_end);
      tok_start = tok_end + 2;
      // fast-forward to } or end, whichever comes first
      while (tok_end < data_end && *tok_end != '}') {
        ++tok_end;
      }

      if (tok_end == data_end) {
        // we're at the end
        emit(STR, tok_start - 2, data_end);
        tok_start = tok_end;
        break;
      } else {
        // found matching }
        emit(STR_I, tok_start, tok_end);
        tok_start = tok_end + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  if (tok_start != data_end) {
    emit(STR, tok_start, data_end);
  }
}

not_dquote_or_escape = [^"\\];
escaped_something = /\\./;
string_constant     = '"' ( not_dquote_or_escape | escaped_something )* '"';

main := |*
  string_constant => interpolate;
  *|;

}%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  //char text[] = "\"hello #{first_name} #{last_name}, how are you?\"";
  //char text[] = "\"#{first_name} is my name.\"";
  //char text[] = "\"#{first_name}#{last_name}\"";
  //char text[] = "\"#{ without finishing brace.\"";
  //char text[] = "\" no starting brace }.\"";

  char *p = &text[0];
  char *pe = (text + strlen(text));
  char *eof = pe;
  int act, cs;
  const char* ts;
  const char* te;

  %% write init;
  %% write exec;

  return 0;
}
```

I am pretty sure you can also do it with jumping to different states using fgoto and such but I've only ever used Ragel for simple scanners so can't really help you there.

Comment: I can get that far, it's just actually getting Ragel to scan the content inside of the `#{}` as well.  I'm not sure how to do it properly.